# Joining independent tables

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i am using Cakephp 3.x.
If let say i have table A, B, C and D.

Table C 'belongsto' A and B. C contain foreign keys of A and B.
Table D 'belongsto' A and B. D contain foreign keys of A and B, which is same as C.

Now i want to display the information in both the table C and D together.
How can i achieve that. 
Thank you.

```
$tableReg1 = TableRegistry::get('C');
$results1 = $tableReg1->find();
$results1->select([
    'id', 'A.name', 'B.number',
    'total' => $results1->func()->sum('amount')
])
->group('A.name')
->order(['A.name' => 'ASC'])
->contain(['A', 'B']);
```

If let say I include the D in this part ->contain(['A','B','D']); 
It will return error: C is not associated with D.

In table C and D, I declare this only.

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->belongsTo('A', [
        'foreignKey' => 'tableAid',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
        //'through' => 'Selections'
    ]);

    $this->belongsTo('B', [
        'foreignKey' => 'tableBid',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);

    $this->table('C');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate more clearly ? like add some code you tried

Comment: @NNem i have added part of the necessary code. thank you.

Comment: have you defined proper relationship between C and D in table ?

Comment: contain D inside related table A or B  ->contain(['A','B'=>[''D']])

Comment: @NNem I don't know how to define the relationship between C and D. could you help me out on this. thanks (i have add the details on top)

Comment: You define relationships with `$this->belongsTo()`, `$this->hasMany()` etc. as you have done with tables `A` and `B`. You cannot use `contain('D')` on table `C` if you haven't set a relationship between them.